# How can I change my imported chunk component to use defineAsyncComponent() in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Usually I import my component using chunk method like this in `Vue.js` **to optimize my page performance especially regarding load speed**, just for information I used `Vue 2`:

```
<template>
 <div>
  ... // some HTML code
  <ChildComponent />
 </div>
</template>

</script>
const ChildComponent = () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ '../components/ChildComponent.vue');

export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    components: { ChildComponent },
}
... //some script
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
... // some styling
</style>
```

but today, my friend tell me that there is this method that `Vue` provide from `version 2.3` for async function and it works the same as chunks as far as I read the [docs in here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#basic-usage), the name of this method is `defineAsyncComponent`, so I try to read it and it seems I can change my code easily into this:

```
</script>
const LoadPopup = () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ '../components/LoadPopup.vue');
const ErrorPopup = () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ '../components/ErrorPopup.vue');

const ChildComponent = defineAsyncComponent({
  // the loader function
  loader: () => import('../components/ChildComponent.vue'),

  loadingComponent: LoadPopup,
  delay: 200,
  errorComponent: ErrorPopup,
  timeout: 3000
})

export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    components: { 
      ChildComponent: ChildComponent
    },
}
... //some script
</script>
```

And here is my question regarding this:

1. what is the different between chunks method that I used in my former code than this method?
2. Is my implementation already right regarding this?
3. And last, is it correct if I want to add more component, then it means I can just make like `const ChildComponent2` with the same way as my `const ChildComponent` and import it right under `components` above?
4. and [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64625688/10158479), why they only use `error` and `loading` instead of `errorComponent` and `loadingComponent`? is it a shorthand for it?

I hope someone can help me to get a better understanding regarding this problem, thankyou